# How to use array_count_values function

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have make a database query with larval.

QUERY :

```
if(Request::ajax()) {
        //On récupère l'ensemble des genres des séries visionnées par l'utilisateur
        $genre_user = DB::table('genres')->select('genres.name')
                                         ->join('seriesgenres', 'genres.id', '=', 'seriesgenres.genre_id')
                                         ->join('series', 'seriesgenres.series_id', '=', 'series.id')
                                         ->join('usersseries', 'series.id', '=', 'usersseries.serie_id')
                                         ->where('usersseries.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        print_r($genre_user);die;
    }
```

After this query I have this array

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Drama
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Action
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Crime
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Drama
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Action & Adventure
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Drama
            )
    )

)
```

I would like to count the number of each values in this array.
To do that i know the array_count_values() fonction but it doesn't work on my result array. The problem come from this line :

```
$counts = array_count_values($genre_user);
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please give the error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it. The function [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) works only for `string` or `integer`:

> Throws `E_WARNING` for every element which is not string or integer.

For complex objects like this, you need to take a different method. Since your PHP doesn't output the warning messages, it is not getting displayed. If you want, you can do something like a transformation.

```
$finalItems = array();
// Loop through the items of the object and push the names into the array.
// ... Logic ...
// And finally do:
array_count_values($finalItems);
```